# Why would Webpack inject React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

In my entry file for webpack I have this:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Layout from './components/Layout';

// ...
dialog = document.createElement("dialog");
ReactDOM.render(<Layout dialog={dialog} />, dialog);
```

This compiles to `React.createElement(o,{dialog:u})`

My script then complains that `React` is not defined since I haven't imported it.

Meanwhile, if I add `import React from 'react';` at the top of the file, the Webpack'ed line turns into `i.a.createElement(o,{dialog:u})`.

Why on earth would it use `React.createElement` in the case where I don't manually import React?

My Webpack config is:

```
const path = require('path');
const os = require('os');

const PLUGINDIR = `${os.homedir()}/Library/Application\ Support/Adobe/Adobe\ XD\ CC/develop/ea44acd5/`;
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  mode: 'production',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(PLUGINDIR),
    filename: 'main.js',
    libraryTarget: "commonjs2"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: "babel-loader",
      options: {
        plugins: [
          "transform-react-jsx"
        ]
      }
    }, {
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
    }]
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Webpack isn't inserting "React.createElement". Babel is doing that as part of transforming the JSX (e.g. `<Layout .../>`). I suspect in the first case, webpack doesn't know what 'React' is, so it doesn't do anything to minify references to it. In the second case webpack does know what it is, so it can deal with it more intelligently and minify it appropriately.

Answer (score -1):

That's because `react` is a [peer dependency](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/) of `react-dom`; you can see that in `react-dom`'s `package.json`. In other words, `react-dom` uses react code internally and expects you to be using a version of `react` that's compatible with the version it has in `package.json`, it won't install a version of `react` by itself.

What does this have to do with webpack? Well, webpack will use either `~/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js` or `~/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.production.min.js` depending on whether you are in dev or prod modes. The code in those 2 files, even though they use react, won't understand react syntax because they were produced using `~/node_modules/react-dom/package.json`, and `react` is listed as a **peer dependency** in that file.

If `react` were to not be a **peer dependecy** of `react-dom` but rather a **normal dependency**, then you could skip the `import React from 'react'`, but then you'd run into issues if you have other dependencies using different versions of `react`.

Lastly, what you see in the bundled file produced by webpack largely depends on the webpack version you use. In essence, webpack creates an object (or an array depending on webpack version) of dependencies. In your case, `i` would be the object holding all dependencies, and `a` would be the key pointing to react. You can find more details about webpack internals in this [guide](https://medium.com/ag-grid/webpack-tutorial-understanding-how-it-works-f73dfa164f01).